# Can we consider case B as the responsible of truth of case A

Tags: logic

I want to prove that certain **case A** is true. Then to do this, assuming by contradiction that the **case A** is false. Then after some number of implications we get a contradiction with a **case B** known to be true.

My question is: Can we consider **case B** as the **responsible** of truth of **case A**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you want to define "responsability". In some sense it is. For example, let's say it is known that $x = 4$ (statement B) and I claim that $x=3$ (statement A) is true.

Now I can say that $x^2=16$, because if $x^2 \neq 16$, then $x \neq 4$ which is in contradiction with the known-to-be-true statement B. In some sense, you can say hat $x=4$ is "responsible" for $x^2=16$

I wouldn't take this too strictly, though, as this notion of "responsability" is not relaly well-defined